# access DD image

Tags: dd, usb-drive, fdisk

I'm trying to analyze a given USB image (.DD) to find out the location of the MFT table. The problem is I'm having trouble to mount the DD image.

When I run fdisk -l ntfs5.dd here's the output that I get:

```
    fdisk -l ntfs5.dd 
    Disk ntfs5.dd: 25 MiB, 26214400 bytes, 51200 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos

Disk identifier: 0x6f20736b

    Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
    ntfs5.dd1        778135908 1919645538 1141509631 544.3G 72 unknown
    ntfs5.dd2        168689522 2104717761 1936028240 923.2G 65 Novell Netware 386
    ntfs5.dd3       1869881465 3805909656 1936028192 923.2G 79 unknown
    ntfs5.dd4                0 3637226495 3637226496   1.7T  d unknown
    Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Here is the command that used to mount the DD image:

```
mount -o loop,offset=$((168689522*512)),ro,noatime,noexec,show_sys_files test1/ntfs5.dd newmountdir/

Here's the error message:
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

my objective is want to use command like mmls, fls and icat to locate the MFT table. I tried on different image(.vdi) and I was able to do so. I just want to understand better on raw file like DD

Comment: No idea what this "DD" format is supposed to be, but the information shown by `fdisk -l` is garbage.  Then, well, garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: dd is a raw file, normally used in forensic to analyze a disk or partition

Comment: Do you just want the 2nd partition to be visible as a single raw file? Maybe `losetup` is what you want.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The first sector is not a partition table.  The OP probably `dd`-ed something else. _shrug_

Answer (score 2):

I was able to read the partitions of a raw image with `kpartx`, like this:

```bash
# mount it to a loop device  
kpartx -a -v  $imagepath

# determine the loop mount point
losetup -a | grep $imagepath

# then fidsk the mounted loop partitions
fdisk -l /dev/mapper/loop1p1

# unmount it 
kpartx -d -v  $imagepath
```